# How do I combine code to print different cells from different tables?

Tags: python

I am pulling data from tables in docx format into xlsx. I can get the data from one to the other (in part) with the below code. This example only shows 4 cases but I need to do it for 40 tables. Is there a way that I can combine this so it looks in all 4 tables with just 1/2 lines of code?

```
table = doc.Tables(5)
table5 = table.Cell(Row =4, Column =2).Range.Text

table = doc.Tables(6)
table6 = table.Cell(Row =4, Column =2).Range.Text

table = doc.Tables(7)
table7 = table.Cell(Row =4, Column =2).Range.Text

table = doc.Tables(8)
table8 = table.Cell(Row =4, Column =2).Range.Text

#print(table5)

combine_Table = {'Name': [table5 , table6, table7, table8]}
labels = ['a','b','c','d']

df = pd.DataFrame(combine_Table , index=labels)
#print("Select specific columns:")
#print(df[['Name']])

df.to_excel("return.xlsx")
```

Libraries
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

Comment: can you show the whole code and what library you use

Comment: I have added the libraries and full code. 
I am new to this and have not used a loop before. Would you be able to show me how that works with the code I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop will do the job...

```py
tables = []
for i in range(5, 9):
    table = doc.Tables(i)
    tables.append(table.Cell(Row =4, Column =2).Range.Text)

combine_Table = {'Name': tables}
labels = ['a','b','c','d']

df = pd.DataFrame(combine_Table , index=labels)

df.to_excel("return.xlsx")
```

Modify the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) values according to how many (and which) tables you have.